# tcp receive data broken

Tags: tcp, protocol-buffers

The situation is: I have a TCP server written is c, TCP client(android app) in Java, using google protobuf to serialize/deserialize; and server sends data to client per second to display.  the data contains(for simple) attribute1/attribute2/attribute3, and the client needs to display the exact data with attribute1/attribute2/attribute3. the data size is more than 1480bytes and varies every second.

the problem is: the TCP client won't get the exact data to display occasionally; for instance, attribute3 is a string, say"2018-12-10 12:00:00", but the TCP client only display "2018-12-".

tried: tcp server and client can't promise the data size, because the data from server varies every second; and it doesn't seem to provide the length of a message by google protobuf. so how can tcp client get the exactly data to display? thx for your help!

Comment: Show relevant code.

Comment: David is absolutely correct in his answer, but to help investigate: this kind of technique is commonly called "framing", with each consecutive message (and the header) being a "frame"

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide on a message format to use over the TCP connection and implement that message format in your code. TCP is not a message protocol and protocol buffers produces messages.

A common technique is to prefix each message with a four-byte integer indicating the size of the message in network byte order. The receiver can then read those four bytes and know how many bytes the protocol buffer message is.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming) for more.

Comment: thx for your answer, as the link point out: "The easiest way to solve this problem is to write the size of each message before you write the message itself", but i don't know the exactly size of the message itself before i written the message.  i can get the size of message with the call "message.ByteSize()" after the message is written.  so i decided to add a four-byte integer member to the message, indicating the length of message, but the protobuf [encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)makes things a litter bit more difficult to get the size of message.

Comment: @zbcwilliam You can leave four bytes in your buffer for the size, then write the message to the buffer after those four bytes, then fill in the four bytes with the message size, then send the whole thing.